From Python project to installer
Let's say I've created an application in Python and the Tkinter library. Everything works as it should and I want to put this project in an installer (.exe).
In the attached image I want to show how the project is structured Image here 
To run the program, I access the file main.py, I am directed to login.py, I enter the credentials and then I am sent to dashboard.py.
Documenting myself on the Internet, I found out that I can do this with Pyinstaller and Inno Setup Compiler.
With Pyinstaller transform main.py into main.exe
pyinstaller main.py --onefile --windowed

The file is generated and I copy it from the 'dist' folder instead of main.py.
I access the file main.exe and everything runs perfectly.
I open the Inno Setup Compiler program, add the necessary data, under 'application main executable file' I choose main.exe, add the rest of the files and folders, some more changes after the watched tutorial and generate the installer. I install the program and everything is fine.
Out of curiosity, I entered the folder where the application was installed. When I saw that apart from main.exe the rest of the files are with .py, the sky fell on me. =))
Anyone who would install the program could have access to the source code.
I redo the whole process and convert the files login.py, dashboard.py into binary. I replace with login.exe and dashboard.exe
pyinstaller main.py --onefile --windowed
pyinstaller login.py --onefile --windowed
pyinstaller dashboard.py --onefile --windowed

It's working. But when I do the same for the rest of the files: function1.py, function2.py, database_connect.py, it doesn't work anymore. It tells me that the files are not found. Even if the binary converted files were placed in the appropriate directory.
I don't know if I did it right or not, but my question is: How can I create an installer without showing my .py files; I want everything to be in binary.
I also tried with auto-py-to-exe but it's the same thing.
============
Something extra: Let's assume that the graphic elements in the program are created by me and I want them to be displayed only in the program interface; in the folder where the program was installed, the images should appear under other extensions (example .dll). Is there any possibility?
Thank you!

"Anyone who would install the program could have access to the source code." Yes, well, anyone can reverse engineer any Pyinstaller app, so these tricks you're trying here (converting modules separately) won't help with that – and as you noticed, your program won't work with those tricks.

I know about reverse engineer. But still, how do I make all the files binary.

are you sure they are .py files and not .pyd?

@Ovidiu All files are binary, some just happen to be readable by humans too. Anyway: if your main.py imports your other modules, pyinstaller --onefile will read the module graph and package everything into one neat zip and then stuff it into the .exe stub – but the source code is still there in a zip, readable if you just extract them.

They are .py files

If you don't like pyinstaller. Why not try py -m pip install pipx was released March 29, 2024.
